# How can I access Visual FoxPro tables from Delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

I've got a legacy collection of `DBF`, `FPT` and `CDX` files left from file organizing software. Judging from CDX and FTP suffixes, I presume it is a Visual FoxPro database. From the first glance into DBF file, it looks like it has [field descriptors](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm) there. I'd like to examine what data stored there and use or extract any useful stuff.

```
00000000:  31 0B 06 0E-2F 00 00 00-08 02 28 01-01 00 00 01  1/   (  
00000010:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 49 40-01 7F 00 00            I@
00000020:  4E 41 4D 45-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 43-01 00 00 00  NAME       C
00000030:  FF 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
00000040:  43 41 54 5F-52 4F 4F 54-49 44 00 42-00 01 00 00  CAT_ROOTID B 
00000050:  08 00 04 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
00000060:  50 52 4E 54-5F 49 44 00-00 00 00 42-08 01 00 00  PRNT_ID    B
00000070:  08 00 04 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
00000080:  41 54 54 52-49 42 53 00-00 00 00 49-10 01 00 00  ATTRIBS    I
00000090:  04 00 04 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
000000A0:  49 53 5F 45-58 43 4C 55-44 45 00 49-1A 01 00 00  IS_EXCLUDE I
000000B0:  04 00 04 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
000000C0:  43 41 54 5F-49 44 00 00-00 00 00 42-1E 01 00 00  CAT_ID     B
000000D0:  08 00 0C 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00   
000000E0:  54 53 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 37-26 01 00 00  TS         7&
000000F0:  08 00 14 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00
```

What I tries so far:

- upgrading out-of-box Windows 7 ODBC driver stub to version 6.01.8629.01
- creating User DNS as "Free Tables Directory" and pointing its path to the file collection
- no tables are listed for that OBDC DNS in variety of tools, like SQL Explorer and SQL Server Import/Export Wizard.
- manual attempt to `SELECT * FROM` any DBF file gives me `[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Not a table.` error.

Also, I tried:

- creating BDE alias with FOXPRO driver
- opening any of DBF files in Database Desktop

Both attempts to open a table resulted in `Corrupt table/index header.` error.

Also, I just tried [tDBF component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdbf/) but it looks abandoned and loaded with Kylix `Libc` dependencies thus not compiles in Delphi w/o fixing that.

## Tons of questions:

- How do I confirm what files are really Visual FoxPro?
- Does symptoms described above indicate real data corruption or just incompatibility/misconfiguration?
- And finally, how to use something modern to access tables and start examining data?

Comment: In relation to the second point - the VFP ODBC driver will open Visual FoxPro and any other version right back to (probably) DOS products like dBase and Clipper - so if it's choking like that it's more likely to be either not actually DBF format, or corrupt as opposed to a config problem. I'm looking at where the field descriptors start there, and to me that's wrong for DBF, they should come later.

Comment: @Alan B, from what I piece together the field descriptor should start at byte offset 32 which seems to be the case above. (I am no DBF expert)

Comment: It looks like it, structure explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975386%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Quickest check is to open the .dbf with excel.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz +1 for Excel, sweet!

Answer (score 3):

**Q: How do I confirm what files are really Visual FoxPro?**

Based on your dbf data dump it would seem to be Visual FoxPro. The first byte has a value of 0x31 which is `Visual FoxPro, autoincrement enabled` according to Microsoft's MSDN documentation of the .dfb Table file structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/st4a0s68(v=vs.80).aspx

Additionall information about the file extensions you mention:

- .dbf = Data for fixed-length fields.
- .cdx = Compound index.
- .fpt = Data for memo fields, images and objects.

**Q: Does symptoms described above indicate real data corruption or just incompatibility/misconfiguration?**

Sorry cannot help you here...

**Q: And finally, how to use something modern to access tables and start examining data?**

I’ve previously managed to access dfb files by using Delphi’s ADO (dbGo) components. I downloaded the FoxPro OLE DB Provider that is included in ”Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable” http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255.

An initial connection string looks as follows:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=[MY_FOXPRO_DIR_PATH];Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE
```

When I study my code I have used a much longer one and unfortunately don't have any notes why. I'm throwing it in anyway:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=[MY_FOXPRO_DIR_PATH];Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";User ID="";Mask Password=False;Cache Authentication=False;Encrypt Password=False;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;DSN="";DELETED=True;CODEPAGE=1252;MVCOUNT=16384;ENGINEBEHAVIOR=90;TABLEVALIDATE=3;REFRESH=5;VARCHARMAPPING=False;ANSI=True;REPROCESS=5
```

Comment: Strange, but for me that MS download you've linked does not contain VFPOLEDB, I've removed it and rolled in a different one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Comment: On overpopulated connection string: I've got the same phenomenon, built connstring interactively and got the same as yours, the only difference (which is regional, I believe)  is CODEPAGE param.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm curious, were you able to access yor files?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. Currently, I'm struggling with whole zoo of errors from OLE DB provider, weirdest of them is "Object was opened".

Comment: Have you tried using excel to open one of your .dbf's as Sertac Akyuz suggested?

Comment: I do not have Excel here, but I've already managed to look inside DBF files using primitive viewer tool http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=553 All of the tables looks OK.

Comment: Rebboot? Copy files to a new location?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to find a copy of Visual Fox Pro, version 9, and see if it will open the files. (The UniversalThread has a VFP section and VFP experts where you can ask the question as well.)

If you can open it in VFP, you can simply copy it to a .CSV or tab-delimited file and you should be able to import it into whatever system you want.

Sometimes VFP tables (.DBF, .CDX, .FPT) are linked to a "data base" (kind of container), which expands their field names and adds things like triggers, etc. Look for a .DBC file somewhere. Or they can be free-standing. I'm not sure what happens if you try to open a VFP table what was part of a DBC (data base container) and you don't have the container available.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I confirm what files are really Visual FoxPro?*
dbf extension and the first byte h31 indicates that it is a Visual FoxPro Table.

*Does symptoms described above indicate real data corruption or just incompatibility/misconfiguration?*
The Microsoft ODBC driver has some problems with VisualFoxPro

*And finally, how to use something modern to access tables and start examining data?*
Best method in my opinion is to use the Apollo database engine from Vista Software.
http://www.apollodb.com/default.asp